# Closing one accordion tab opening the other one by default

Tags: html, bootstrap-accordion

Bootstrap accordion is not working correctly.If i click on one accordion tab it is closing the other one and some times it is closing and opening again.For the first time it is working fine but for the next time its not working correctly.If i click on one tab it is closing the other one or else it will be opened by default after closing

```
<div class="col-lg-6">              
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                  Notify Users
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <select id="selection" class="form-control">
                                                    <option>All Users</option>
                                                    <option>Metronomic</option>
                                                    <option>Fairfax Users</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <select id="selection" class="form-control">
                                                    <option>App Notify</option>
                                                    <option>Email</option>                  
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notification title here..." id="title">
                                    </div>     
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="last">Sub Title</label>
                                         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notification sub title here..." id="sub-title">
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="notificationcontent">Notification Content</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="" id="notificationcontent"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Notification</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                </div>                  
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                  Notify Users
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <select id="selection" class="form-control">
                                                    <option>All Users</option>
                                                    <option>Metronomic</option>
                                                    <option>Fairfax Users</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <select id="selection" class="form-control">
                                                    <option>App Notify</option>
                                                    <option>Email</option>                  
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notification title here..." id="title">
                                    </div>     
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="last">Sub Title</label>
                                         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notification sub title here..." id="sub-title">
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="notificationcontent">Notification Content</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="" id="notificationcontent"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Notification</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                </div>                  
            </div>
```

Comment: this same code is working fine for me .!

Comment: The [code](https://jsfiddle.net/1gs2vfnj/) works just fine. Make sure to add all scripts (popper and bootstrap js files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wrongly assigned `data-parent="#accordion"`, you have to assign this for Collapse div and use single parent `<div id="accordion"></div>`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
  <div class="col-lg-6"> 

                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="row">        
                    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                  Notify Users
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <select id="selection" class="form-control">
                                                    <option>All Users</option>
                                                    <option>Metronomic</option>
                                                    <option>Fairfax Users</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <select id="selection" class="form-control">
                                                    <option>App Notify</option>
                                                    <option>Email</option>                  
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notification title here..." id="title">
                                    </div>     
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="last">Sub Title</label>
                                         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notification sub title here..." id="sub-title">
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="notificationcontent">Notification Content</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="" id="notificationcontent"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Notification</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    
                                <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                  Notify Users
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <select id="selection" class="form-control">
                                                    <option>All Users</option>
                                                    <option>Metronomic</option>
                                                    <option>Fairfax Users</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <select id="selection" class="form-control">
                                                    <option>App Notify</option>
                                                    <option>Email</option>                  
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notification title here..." id="title">
                                    </div>     
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="last">Sub Title</label>
                                         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notification sub title here..." id="sub-title">
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="notificationcontent">Notification Content</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="" id="notificationcontent"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Notification</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                </div>                  
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: It is getting one by one but i need to get this side by side

Comment: can you explain the question how you want

Comment: You are displaying the accordions one by one but  i need it side by side